# Using enum and switch statement in Java

Tags: java, enums

I'm trying to write a calculator but when testing with any operation of type Enum (+,-,/,*)  and clicking on the equals button the program goes directly into the default statement. How can I fix this?

```
public enum OpType {
Plus('+'),Minus('-'),Division('/'),Multiplication('X'),Void(' ');
private char operation;

private OpType(char operation) {
    setOperation(operation);
}

private OpType() {
    this(' ');
}

public static OpType getPlus() {
    return Plus;
}

public static OpType getVoid() {
    return Void;
}

public static OpType getMinus() {
    return Minus;
}

public static OpType getDivision() {
    return Division;
}

public static OpType getMultiplication() {
    return Multiplication;
}

 public void setOperation(char operation) {
    this.operation = operation;
}

public char getOperation() {
    return operation;
}


private double dblResult;
private OpType opType;

/**
 * Creates new form Calculator1
 */

public Calculator1(double dblResult, OpType opType) {
   setDblResult(dblResult);
    setOpType(opType);

}



public OpType getOpType() {
    return opType;
}

public void setOpType(OpType opType) {
    this.opType = opType;
}


public Calculator1() {
    initComponents();
    opType = OpType.Void;
}

public double getDblResult() {
    return dblResult;
}

public void setDblResult(double dblResult) {
    this.dblResult = dblResult;
}
```

//...

```
private void oneActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    if("0".equals(textField.getText())){
        textField.setText("1");
    }
    else{
    textField.setText(String.format(textField.getText() + "1"));
    }
}                                   

private void twoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    if("0".equals(textField.getText())){
        textField.setText("2");
    }
    else{
    textField.setText(String.format(textField.getText() + "2"));
    }

}                                   

private void threeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    if("0".equals(textField.getText())){
        textField.setText("3");
    }
    else{
    textField.setText(String.format(textField.getText() + "3"));
    }
}                                     

private void fourActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    if("0".equals(textField.getText())){
        textField.setText("4");
    }
    else{
    textField.setText(String.format(textField.getText() + "4"));
    }
}                                    

private void fiveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    if("0".equals(textField.getText())){
        textField.setText("5");
    }
    else{
    textField.setText(String.format(textField.getText() + "5"));
    }
}                                    

private void sixActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    if("0".equals(textField.getText())){
        textField.setText("6");
    }
    else{
    textField.setText(String.format(textField.getText() + "6"));
    }
}                                   

private void sevenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    if("0".equals(textField.getText())){
        textField.setText("7");
    }
    else{
    textField.setText(String.format(textField.getText() + "7"));
    }
}                                     

private void eightActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    if("0".equals(textField.getText())){
        textField.setText("8");
    }
    else{
    textField.setText(String.format(textField.getText() + "8"));
    }
}                                     

private void nineActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    if("0".equals(textField.getText())){
        textField.setText("9");
    }
    else{
    textField.setText(String.format(textField.getText() + "9"));
    }
}                                    

private void zeroActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    if("0".equals(textField.getText())){
        textField.setText("0");
    }
    else{
    textField.setText(String.format(textField.getText() + "0"));
    }
}                                    

private void plusActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    dblResult = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
    OpType op1 = OpType.Plus;
    textField.setText(String.format("%s",op1.getOperation()));
}                                    

private void minusActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    dblResult = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
    OpType op2 = OpType.Minus;
    textField.setText(String.format("%s",op2.getOperation()));
}                                     

private void multiplyActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    dblResult = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
    OpType op3 = OpType.Multiplication;
    textField.setText(String.format("%s",op3.getOperation()));
}                                        

private void divideActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    dblResult = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
    OpType op4 = OpType.Division;
    textField.setText(String.format("%s",op4.getOperation()));
}                                      

private void decimalActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    String dot = ".";
    textField.setText(String.format(textField.getText() + "%s", dot));
}                                       

private void equalsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    double result;
    switch(opType){
        case Plus: 
            result = dblResult + Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
            textField.setText(String.format("%f",result));
            break;
        case Minus:
            result = dblResult + Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
            textField.setText(String.format("%f",result));
            break;
        case Division:
            result = dblResult + Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
            textField.setText(String.format("%f",result));
            break;
        case Multiplication:
            result = dblResult + Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
            textField.setText(String.format("%f",result));
            break;
        default:
            textField.setText("error");
    }
}
```

Comment: in `equalsActionPerformed()` method, how do you know the value of `opType`? - it is not being passed as a parameter to it

Comment: You're using an `enum` as a class and putting code inside it? That seems a little strange to me.

Comment: @blurfus before using equalsActionPerformed() I use plusActionPerformed() for example and intiliazing OpType to Plus.Therefore in the switch statement OpType should be set to Plus and falling directly to the default statement.
P.S Sorry for the bad english

Comment: but when you initialize `OpType` to `Plus` you don't pass it to the method for it to use.  You also don't initalize the `Calculator`'s `opType`.  In summary, you initialize `OpType` and then you don't use it at all afterwards.  Maybe replacing `switch(opType)` with `switch(Calculator1.getOpType())` would help?

Comment: No,I tried that too but it still gets the default case..

Comment: well, `Calculator1` knows nothing about this method and this method knows nothing about `Calculator1` - how are these tied up together?

Comment: I figured it out in the Action methods I declared OpType instead of opType..Thanks for the help!

Comment: @merlin2011 That's a totally reasonable thing to do in Java; enums are effectively a static set of instances of a particular class assigned to some helpful name, not just simple numeric values as in other languages. Of course you can abuse this, but it can also make your code much simpler and easier to read.

Comment: @I.Anchev Why do you have getters for an enum? All of the instances are already public and static, there is no need to provide accessors like that. Your 'setOperation' method is also dubious, just have the constructor set the field directly as it should never change after enum-instantiation time.